# Aplicar estilos a un form en Django

Tags: django, django-forms

tengo el siguiente codigo en el que aplico estilos a un form, si se aplica a una vista basada en funciones, pero queria saber porque no funciona en una vista basada en clases y como tendria que hacer

```
class BooksForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = booksTable
    fields = ['name', 'author']
    labels = {
        'name': 'Titulo',
        'author': 'Autor'
    }
    widgets= {
        'name':forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        'author':forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En algunas vistas basadas en clase se puede utilizar los forms como ejemplo te coloco una vista del proyecto que actualmente realizo

```
class DiasUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'admins/form_dias.html'
    model = Dias
    form_class = DiasForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('admins_app:dias')
```

En esta vista uso el modelo y el form

Te dejo esta documentación donde te indican las vistas y que métodos puedes modificar

> https://ccbv.co.uk/

Suerte

Comment: Muchas gracias Erick, yo estaba usando los campos form y field en la view, y usando form_class solamente me funciono